# Use custom webpack in angular application

Tags: angular, web, webpack

I want to run webpack in angular application so I wrote the code like this .

**package.json file**

```
"scripts": {
"start_ar": "ng build --watch --configuration=dev_ar",
 },

"devDependencies": {
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.1.4",
"file-loader": "^1.1.11",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
"url-loader": "^1.0.1"
 }
```

**In angular.json file**

```
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./webpack.config.js",
          "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
        },
```

**In webpack.config.js**

```
   module.exports = {
        module : {
          rules: [
             {
             "test": /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ani|ico|cur)$/,
             "loader": "url-loader",
              "options": {
              "name": "[name].[hash:7].[ext]",
              "limit": 10000,
               "outputPath": "../assets/img/",
              "publicPath": "src/assets/img/"
              }
            }]}};
```

But the problem is that the image still as is , like that the webpack dose not run , 
I have no error but I didn't see any change to the image , Is there anything missing in this code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular cli does not let you modify `webpack` file anymore. Instead you should use angular builders to perform modification

One of the the builder is [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus). You should checkout it's documentation for it's complete feature list

Following steps are taken from it's documentation

> Add ngx-build-plus: `ng add ngx-build-plus`
>
> Note: If you want to add it to specific sub project in your projects
>   folder, use the --project switch to point to it: `ng add ngx-build-plus --project getting-started`
>
> Remark: This step installs the package via npm and updates your
>   angular.json so that your project uses custom builders for ng serve
>   and ng build.
>
> Add a file `webpack.partial.js` to the root of your (sub-)project:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "VERSION": JSON.stringify("4711")
        })
    ] } Use the global variable VERSION in your app.component.ts:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare const VERSION: string;

@Component({ selector: 'app-root', templateUrl: './app.component.html', styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] }) export class AppComponent { title = 'Version: ' + VERSION; } Start your application with the --extra-webpack-config switch pointing to your partial webpack config:
```

> `ng serve --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js -o` If your project is a CLI based sub project, use the --project switch too:
>
> `ng serve --project getting-started -o --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js`
>    Hint: Consider creating a npm script for this
>   command.

So in your case the content of of `webpack.partial.js` will be

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
        module : {
          rules: [
             {
             "test": /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ani|ico|cur)$/,
             "loader": "url-loader",
              "options": {
              "name": "[name].[hash:7].[ext]",
              "limit": 10000,
               "outputPath": "../assets/img/",
              "publicPath": "src/assets/img/"
              }
            }]}};
```

Comment: When i try to add ngx-build-plus i had this ERROR : The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support.

Comment: which version of cli are you using? see (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-custom-webpack-config)this for alternate.

Comment: "@angular/cli": "^7.1.4",